# MongoDb message source with date parameters

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm having a situation with one of my spring integration.
I have a spring integration which process files from a SFTP server, then leave them on the server after. I use a mongodb metadata store to be able to have several instances taking the files without collision.
What I want to do:

- make a mongo db query which will search files treated with modification date between x and Y days.
- delete those files
- the action is fired by a poller.

What I want to do is something like that:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processProduct() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mongoMessageSource(mongoDbFactory),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.cron(cron)))
            .enrichHeaders(m -> m.header("errorChannel", deleteFileErrorChannel))
            .split()
            .channel(deleteFileChannel())
            .get();
}


@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> mongoMessageSource(MongoDbFactory mongo) {
    long innerBoundary = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    long outerBoundary = Instant.now().plus(XXXXX).toEpochMilli();

    log.info("Delete file with modification date between {} and {}", outerBoundary, innerBoundary);
    String expression = new StringBuilder()
            .append("{value: { $gte: \"")
            .append(outerBoundary)
            .append("\", $lt : \"")
            .append(innerBoundary)
            .append("\"}}")
            .toString();
    log.info("Running mongo query {}", expression);

    MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongo, new LiteralExpression(expression));
    messageSource.setExpectSingleResult(false);
    messageSource.setEntityClass(MetaDataStore.class);
    messageSource.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("treated_file"));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow deleteFileFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(deleteFileChannel())
            //Add file name and directory to header
            .enrichHeaders(m -> m
                    .header("file_remoteDirectory", sourceFtpDirectory)
                    .headerExpression("file_remoteFile", "payload.id")
            )
            //Delete files
            .handle(Sftp
                    .outboundGateway(
                            sourceFtpSessionFactory,
                            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.RM,
                            "headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + '/' + headers['file_remoteFile']")
            )
            .get();
}
```

The problem is that the mongoMessageSource being a bean, the query fired is always the same. 
How can I make a spring integration which fire a mongo query every X times with different parameter values then delete the files? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go right way, but you should consider some external bean which will return for you a new query each time the poll calls `MongoDbMessageSource.receive()`.

I mean that your second ctor argument for the `MongoDbMessageSource` must be something like:

```
Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("@myQueryBean.getQuery()");
MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongo, expression);
```

Where that `myQueryBean` is some bean with an appropriate logic to build a new MongoDb query each time that `getQuery()` is called. In our case it is done by the poller on the `MongoDbMessageSource`.

Comment: @DamienWalle could you please post your solution

Comment: @DamienWalle It worked like charm, thanks much for this great solution. I will be posting my complete solution soon to help others like edwin